# global variable is empty within function

Tags: jquery, ajax, variables, global-variables, scope

I have this code http://jsfiddle.net/meridius/ysDGm/ where the problem is with `out.id` variable in `append` part. For reasons I can't explain, that variable is empty in that part.

I think the problem is with that variable's scope and I tried everything but with no luck.
Please note, the problem is NOT with AJAX, that works fine!

Here is shortened version of that Fiddle:

```
<tr>
    <td>one</td>
    <td>
        <select name="zadavatel">
            <option value="0">-- vyberte --</option>
            <option value="new">-- nový zadavatel --</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

```
var out = {};
$('select').bind("change", function() {
  if ($(this).val() == "new") {
    var nazev = prompt('Question', 
                $(this).parent().siblings(':first-child').text());
    if (nazev == null) {
      $(this).val($.data(this, 'current'));
      return false;
    } else {
      var pole2 = {};
      pole2["nazev"] = nazev;
      $.ajax({
        type    : "POST",
        cache    : false,
        url      : "./pokus_zad.php",
        data    : JSON.stringify(pole2),
        success  : function(data) {
          out = JSON.parse(data);  //data.id
        }
      });
      out.id = 15;  // this work, but it SHOULD work without it (with AJAX)
      $(this).closest('table').find('select').each(
        function() {
          $(this).append($('<option>', { "value" : out.id }).text(nazev));
        });
      $(this).closest('select').val(out.id).attr('selected', 'selected');
    }
  }
  $.data(this, 'current', $(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Search for "return jquery ajax value". You will find enough duplicates. The cause is very simple: *the value of the [global] variable has not been set at the point it is used*. Thats all.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/560307/how-do-i-edit-a-global-variable-in-a-jquery-each-function?rq=1 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6917796/extjs-return-ajax-return-value , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8532082/return-value-of-post-call , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31129/how-can-i-return-a-variable-from-a-getjson-function?rq=1 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632039/return-value-from-ajax-call , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181665/is-there-a-way-to-return-a-value-xml-in-my-case-from-a-jquery-ajax-call?rq=1

Comment: AJAX is asynchronous, so code flow continues while the ajax call is being performed. You are trying to use your `out` variable before it gets set. Try moving the code after your ajax call into the success callback

Comment: The rest of your code executes while the ajax call is doing its thing. Put your in the success function or setup a callback, or eve better a deferred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great, thanks guys!

Based on your suggestions I moved my append code to success callback of AJAX function **AND** I also had to create variable for $(this) since it is different $(this) inside AJAX than it is outside. ;)

The working JQuery part now looks like this:

```
var out = {};
$('select').bind("change", function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "new") {
        var nazev = prompt('Zadejte název zadavatele', $(this).parent().siblings(':first-child').text());
        if (nazev == null) {
            $(this).val($.data(this, 'current'));
            return false;
        } else {
            var select = $(this);
            var pole2 = {};
            pole2["nazev"] = nazev;
            $.ajax({
                type        : "POST",
                cache       : false,
                url         : "./pokus_zad.php",
                data        : JSON.stringify(pole2),
                success : function(data) {
                    out = JSON.parse(data); //data.id
                    select.closest('table').find('select').each(
                        function() {
                            $(this).append($('<option>', { "value" : out.id }).text(nazev));
                        });
                    select.val(out.id).attr('selected', 'selected');
                }
            });
        }
    }
    $.data(this, 'current', $(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

AJAX is asynchronous, and therefore the setting of the `out` variable from within it will happen after the rest of the function.

```
      $.ajax({
        type    : "POST",
        cache    : false,
        url      : "./pokus_zad.php",
        data    : JSON.stringify(pole2),
        success  : function(data) {
          out = JSON.parse(data);  //data.id
          $(this).closest('table').find('select').each(
            function() {
              $(this).append($('<option>', { "value" : out.id }).text(nazev));
            });
          $(this).closest('select').val(out.id).attr('selected', 'selected');
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put the append code inside the success block. Because the ajax call is asynchronous the append statement runs before the 'out' variable is set by the ajax callback.

```
var out = {};
$('select').bind("change", function() {
  if ($(this).val() == "new") {
    var nazev = prompt('Question', 
                $(this).parent().siblings(':first-child').text());
    if (nazev == null) {
      $(this).val($.data(this, 'current'));
      return false;
    } else {
      var pole2 = {};
      pole2["nazev"] = nazev;
      $.ajax({
        type    : "POST",
        cache    : false,
        url      : "./pokus_zad.php",
        data    : JSON.stringify(pole2),
        success  : function(data) {
          out = JSON.parse(data);  //data.id
          $(this).closest('table').find('select').each(
            function() {
              $(this).append($('<option>', { "value" : out.id }).text(nazev));
            });
          $(this).closest('select').val(out.id).attr('selected', 'selected');
        }
      });
    }
  }
  $.data(this, 'current', $(this).val());
});
```